# What is the difference between a tab, viewport, window, split and buffer?

Tags: buffers, vim-windows, split, tabbed-user-interface

What is the difference between the following in vim:

- buffer
- window
- viewport
- split
- tab

Answer (score 18):

A **buffer** is the in-memory text of a file. It may differ from the saved version of the file.

A **window** is a view of a buffer. You can have two (or more) windows editing different parts of the same buffer.

A **viewport** is synonymous with a window.

A **tab** page contains one or more windows. You can see what windows are in which tab with `:tabs`.

A **split** is where the screen space previously occupied by one window is then allocated to two windows. A window can be split either horizontally (`:split`) or vertically (`:vsplit`), and a window inside a split can itself be split again.

Further reading:
[`:help windows`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html), 
[`:help :tab-page`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/tabpage.txt.html), 
[Buffers, windows and tabs](https://sanctum.geek.nz/arabesque/buffers-windows-tabs/) - Tom Ryder