# How do I select the other files in a tab?

Tags: vim-windows, tabbed-user-interface

When I run the `tabs` command the file `mix.exs` in the same tab as `NERDTree`, (i.e. tab 2), but I can't access it, as it seems to be in the background or hidden in some way. How can I bring `mix.exs` to the front or even move it to its own tab?

```
:tabs                                    
Tab page 1                               
    myfuncs/funcs_router.ex              
Tab page 2                               
>   NERD_tree_2                          
    mix.exs                              
Tab page 3                               
    myfuncs/docsplug.ex                  
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? It look like the file is open in a window in the current tab, so it should be visible.

Comment: @muru Yes I used `gt2 `and `Ctrl-ww` to access it. I am new to vim and grok that an active tab is like a "window"

Comment: You might want to read http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/9017/205

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to read [vim tab madness](http://joshldavis.com/2014/04/05/vim-tab-madness-buffers-vs-tabs/)

I used to use tabs too, but now I only use buffers, for me this is easier.

In the screen above, you can directly enter commands.
If you use for example: `:tabfind` followed by the filename, it will be opened in a new ... ah ... erm ... tab!

HTH!